# R multiple condition filtering/deleting

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I'm a former SAS user and am trying to delete cases based on multiple conditions using the "filter" function in the tidyverse and am running into problems with the intersection of multiple conditions. In my reprex, I'm trying to delete cars (mtcars dataset) that have BOTH 8 cylinders AND a qsec 18 and over. In the mtcars dataset there are only 2 cars that meet both of these conditions (Merc 450SLC and Caddilac Fleetwood). There are 32 observations in the mtcars dataset, so the solution should return 30 observations based on the criteria.

I've tried using filter(cyl != 8, qsec < 18), but that deletes all 8 cylinder cars and all cars with qsecs 18 and above (resulting in only 5 observations). Using "&" yields the same result. Lots of googling didn't result in a solution, so any help is appreciated.

```
#Reprex: 
filterdata <- mtcars %>%
   filter(qsec < 18 & cyl != 8)
```

Thanks,
Wythe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want to remove :

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%  filter(cyl == 8 & qsec >= 18)
```

So you can negate the condition to get the rows that you want to keep.

```
mtcars %>%  filter(!(cyl == 8 & qsec >= 18))
```

The approach which you were trying needed OR (|) condition.

```
mtcars %>%  filter(cyl != 8 | qsec < 18)
```

PS - There is only one row which has `qsec >= 18`. `Caddilac Fleetwood` has `qsec` as 17.98.

Comment: Thanks Ronak, this worked perfectly! I'll definitely be using the filter(!()) expression for deleting cases. Best.

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can use `subset`

```
subset(mtcars, !(cyl == 8 & qsec >= 18))
```